# Конвертировать DOCX в PDF

Tags: c#, vb.net

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно программно получить PDF из DOCX (MS Office на ПК ставить нельзя).
Пробовал библиотеку Spire.Office, всё прекрасно работает, но она триальная (пишет это на каждой странице). Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли бесплатные библиотеки, или ссылку на полную версию (платной).

Comment: А OpenOffice?

Comment: @alexlz тоже нет, я же не буду ставить 122 МБ OpenOffice чтобы , выгрузить отчёт работы программы в PDF.

Comment: А откуда берётся docx и можно ли его оттуда вывести на печать (в postscript)? Если можно, то далее ghostscript'ом ps -> pdf... (Правда размер может оказаться большим)

Comment: @alexlz мне нужно взять 1.docx и превратить его в 1.pdf , язык VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот [эту](http://www.aspose.com/) библиотечку.

Вообще можно сделать так:
программа загружает файл 1.docx на какой-нибудь онлайн конвертер, а потом получает ссылку на скачивание (с этого сайта) и скачивает уже [1.pdf](http://1.pdf). Если всегда есть соединение с интернетом, то можно использовать этот вариант.